libmariadb3 and libmariadb-dev not installing in ubuntu
When I try to install libmariadb3 or libmariadb-dev I'm getting the error Err:2 https://dlm.mariadb.com/re po/mariadb- server/10.5/repo/ubuntu focal/main amd64 mariadb-server-10.5 amd64 1 :10.5.25+maria~ubu2004
403 Forbidden
I tried to install it using the package and the step-by-step instructions in the mariadb documentation.
